# How to get an embedded function to run multiple times

Tags: javascript

The question I have is how to I get multiple instances of a function to run.  Here is my function below - A simple fade function.  Problem I'm having is that when it is called a second time it abandons the first call.  So if a user clicks on a button it will display a message which fades.

If the user clicks on another button the previous fading message just stops at the current opacity level.

**?**

What is the stopping mechanism?  Where did the previous function go?

**The function**

```
function newEffects(element, direction, max_time ) 
{
    newEffects.arrayHold = [];
    newEffects.arrayHold[element.id] = 0;

    function next() 
    {
        newEffects.arrayHold[element.id] += 10;
        if ( direction === 'up' )
        {
            element.style.opacity = newEffects.arrayHold[element.id] / max_time;
        }
        else if ( direction === 'down' )
        {
            element.style.opacity = ( max_time - newEffects.arrayHold[element.id] ) / max_time;
        }
        if ( newEffects.arrayHold[element.id] <= max_time ) 
        {
            setTimeout( next, 10 );
        }
    }
    next();
    return true;
};
```

**The Call**

```
newEffects(this.element, 'down', 4000 );
```

**Old Object**

```
/**
 *    Effects - causes all elements that are fading to sync. to same opacity level as they share the same elapsed time.
 */

var Effects = function( element ) 
{
    this.element = element;
};

Effects.prototype.fade = function( direction, max_time ) 
{
    Effects.elapsed = 0;
    var persist_element = this.element;
    function next() 
    {
        Effects.elapsed += 10;
        if ( direction === 'up' )
        {
            persist_element.style.opacity = Effects.elapsed / max_time;
        }
        else if ( direction === 'down' )
        {
            persist_element.style.opacity = ( max_time - Effects.elapsed ) / max_time;
        }
        if ( Effects.elapsed <= max_time ) 
    {
            setTimeout( next, 10 );
        }
    }
    next();
    return true;
};
```

Comment: I'm clicking Sign Up and Sign In but nothing's happening.

Comment: I put the old code back in which uses the same elapsed time for each function call....so now the opacities should sync..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function newEffects(element, direction, max_time ) 
{
    var mt=max_time;
    var dir=direction; 
    var el=document.getElementById(element);
    var newEffects={};
    newEffects.arrayHold = [];
    newEffects.arrayHold[el.id] = 0;

    function next() 
    {
        newEffects.arrayHold[el.id] += 10;
        if ( dir === 'up' )
        {
            el.style.opacity = newEffects.arrayHold[el.id] / mt;
        }
        else if ( dir === 'down' )
        {
            el.style.opacity = ( mt - newEffects.arrayHold[el.id] ) / mt;
        }
        if ( newEffects.arrayHold[el.id] <= mt ) 
        {
            setTimeout( next, 10 );
        }
    } next();
};
```

An example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xYbWq/3/).

> Declare every variable using var keyword inside the parent function to
>   keep separate instance of each items, this is how clouser works.

Comment: element is the element...no need to getElementById(element)

Comment: I answered it depending on your question before the edit (as a function only) and it's working here http://jsfiddle.net/xYbWq/3/.

Comment: I'm keeping separate opacity level for each items, is it right ?

Comment: it does not work in the fiddle either...set them both to black and you will see the flicker...

Comment: I didn't see any flicker, do you want to apply the same opacity level to every elements, like http://jsfiddle.net/xYbWq/4/

Comment: Can you enable the newEffects={};

Comment: I just did...now you will get a flicker...if you click on the same element multiple times

Comment: Look at Arxanas's code...perhaps this is a better approach as it uses the new keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling next() recursively.  I'm surprised your code isn't crashing.

Comment: this is the best way to write a fade function by setting the opacity and than setting a timer to re-set it after t time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
function foo() {
    foo.bar = 5;
    alert(foo.bar); // alerts 5
}
foo();
alert(foo.bar); // alerts 5 instead of undefined!
```

Foo is an object that has properties, but can also be called as a function. Any properties that are set will persist, even outside the function call. (In fact, this is a way to make a [Javascript pseudo-class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/), which is useful for its own purposes.)

What you can do instead is return new instances of this "class", in one of the two following ways:

```
function fadeEffect(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.fadeTimeLeft = 1000;
    this.fade = function() {
        this.fadeElement.style.opacity -= .01; // Replace with working
                                               // opacity decreaser.
        this.fadeTimeLeft -= 1;
        if (this.fadeTimeLeft > 0) {
            setTimeout(this.fade, 10);
        }
    }
}

signInButtonFade = new fadeEffect(document.getElementById("signinfade"));
```

Or in Javascript's object-literal notation, which you may know better as [JSON](http://www.json.org/):

```
function fadeEffect(element) {
    return {
        "fadeElement": element,
        "fadeTimeLeft": 1000,
        "fade": function() {
            this.fadeElement.style.opacity -= .01; // Replace with working
                                                   // opacity decreaser.
            this.fadeTimeLeft -= 1;
            if (this.fadeTimeLeft > 0) {
                setTimeout(this.fade, 10);
            }
        },
        "init": function() {
            // When using this format, no code is executed automatically,
            // so we have a "constructor" that we execute manually when
            // making the object.
            this.fade();
        }
    }
}

signInButtonFade = generateFade();
signInButtonFade.init();
```

(Obviously, the actual opacity decreasing is not functional.)

You can also store each of these fade effects in an array, and then check to see if there are any previous fade effects that are being applied to an element. If there are, then either you can stop that fade or hijack it into fading the other way, or something else entirely.

```
fadeArray = new Array();
fadeArray.push(new fadeEffect(document.getElementById("fadeElement"));

// Do other adding fade stuff, etc...

// Now we add a new fade effect. This could easily be put into a function:
fadeEffectAlreadyExists = false;
for (i in fadeArray) {
    if (i.element == document.getElementById("fadeElement2")) {
        fadeEffectAlreadyExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!fadeEffectAlreadyExists) {
    fadeArray.push(new fadeEffect(document.getElementById("fadeElement2")));
}
```

While this is fine and all (and in my opinion, the correct way to do it), you can probably keep your existing function by replacing each instance of "newEffects" in the function body with "this", and then use `fade = new newEffects(element, direction, max_time);` since it already shares quite a bit in common with the first approach.

Comment: Thanks...would you consider Sheikh Heera's way another valid way?

Comment: It appears that using the `var` keyword sort of "anchors" member variables to the particular instance of the function. While it's certainly valid, it may not be obvious that the `var` keyword does that. For that matter, using the `new` keyword acts the same as if you put a `var` before each of your declarations.

Comment: nothing in Javascript is obvious to me...it's a rubicks cube.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming :P